# Is there a way to make a TextView use the Spinner style?

Tags: android, textview, android-view

I want to have a TextView look like a Spinner. When you click, a dialog with the choices for the TextView appear. No, I don't want to use a Spinner. I want to use a TextView.

Comment: Why not spinner? You can use spinner with transparent background, which will remove the default background of spinner and make fill of textview...

Comment: What is the code you have already tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
style="?android:attr/spinnerStyle"
```

Comment: Do you know how to do the same programmatically?