# Setting style to TextView for look alike Spinner is not working

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, textview, spinner

I am working on a textview which should look like Spinner ,on click of it i am opening a new Activity.i Tried many solutions like:

```
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar"
```

or

```
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"
```

also tried with

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/right_icon"
```

but in this case textview is looking weird.it is not similar to spinner in anyway

My Xml Code

```
 <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Basic Details"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            style="?android:attr/spinnerStyle"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

This code isn't working.

Help me out

Comment: Duplicate :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27596611/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-textview-use-the-spinner-style

Comment: i already tried it ..its not working.Thats why i put it another question

Comment: You did not mention it. And upload your `xml` code for more specific question. Because many of solution worked and I have used it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make a TextView use the Spinner style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27596611/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-textview-use-the-spinner-style)

Comment: can you guys can post any screenshots of working .also tell me the version of android on which its working..

Comment: can anyone told me whats wrong with my code

Answer (score 0):

i think you can try this

```
<TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:text="Basic Details"
     android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
     android:textSize="18sp"
     style="?android:attr/spinnerStyle"
     android:textStyle="bold" />
```